# Error when declaring a var of type UInt

Tags: ios, swift

I just installed the Xcode 6 Beta and started trying out some code in the PlayGround.

`var unsignedVal: UInt = 25` throws me the runtime error

[image]

But changing it to `var unsignedVal: UInt32 = 25` makes it fine.

Any clarification on this please?

Comment: Smells like a bug. It works as expected when executed in a normal Xcode project.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say so. If I just put `UInt(25)` on a line in a playground I get the same stack trace. If I put `println(Uint(25))` it works. Perhaps a bug in the value outputting code in the playground, or something? Looks like the actual *code* is executing okay, but maybe the playground crashes when trying to print the result of the statement (which is different if you println() the value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. As an experiment, this works in a playground to accomplish the same result:

```
var unsignedVal: UInt
println(unsignedVal = 25)
// unsignedVal is now a UInt with the value 25
```

...but I get your crash whenever I do anything that would have the playground sidebar itself actually print the value of the UInt (which I think is why wrapping it in a println, which prints the value to the console, but *not* to the playground sidebar display, works.)

Simplest case I found to reproduce the bug is this single line in a Playground:

```
UInt(25)
```